# How to do Bspline in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, interpolation, spline

I'm trying to plot a `Bspline` with my regression data, but it is not working. The graph shows the scatter plot but without the interpolated `spline`:

```
#library##
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyfit
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import BSpline
##select x,y ##
select2 = df.groupby('Customer_Age')['Customer_Gender'].value_counts().rename('count').reset_index()
x = pd.DataFrame(select2['Customer_Age']).values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = select2['count'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
## polinomal ##
pre_process = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
x_poly = pre_process.fit_transform(x)
##predict#
pr_model = LinearRegression()
pr_model.fit(x_poly, y)
y_pred = pr_model.predict(x_poly)
##B-spline##
t, c, k = interpolate.splrep(x, y, s=0, k=4)
N = 100
xmin, xmax = x.min(), x.max()
xx = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, N)
spline = interpolate.BSpline(t, c, k, extrapolate=False)
##plot##
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', label='Original points')
plt.plot(xx, spline(xx), 'r', label='BSpline')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

My approach results in these outputs for `t, c, k`:

```
    t: [17.  17.  17.  17.  17.  18.  18.5 19.  19.5 20.  20.5 21.  21.5 22.
     22.5 23.  23.5 24.  24.5 25.  25.5 26.  26.5 27.  27.5 28.  28.5 29.
     29.5 30.  30.5 31.  31.5 32.  32.5 33.  33.5 34.  34.5 35.  35.5 36.
     36.5 37.  37.5 38.  38.5 39.  39.5 40.  40.5 41.  41.5 42.  42.5 43.
     43.5 44.  44.5 45.  45.5 46.  46.5 47.  47.5 48.  48.5 49.  49.5 50.
     50.5 51.  51.5 52.  52.5 53.  53.5 54.  54.5 55.  55.5 56.  56.5 57.
     57.5 58.  58.5 59.  59.5 60.  60.5 61.  61.5 62.  62.5 63.  63.5 64.
     64.5 65.  65.5 66.  66.5 67.  67.5 68.  68.5 69.  69.5 70.  70.5 71.
     71.5 72.  72.5 73.  73.5 74.  74.5 75.  75.5 76.  76.5 77.5 78.  78.5
     79.5 80.5 81.  81.5 83.  84.  84.5 85.5 87.  87.  87.  87.  87. ]
    c: [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
     nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
     nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
     nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
     nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
     nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
     nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
     nan nan nan nan nan nan nan  6.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
    k: 4
```

[image]

This is the structure of my data for x and y:

```
Customer_Age    Customer_Gender count
0   17  M   846
1   17  F   460
2   18  M   970
3   18  F   790
4   19  M   1188
```

Comment: i was edited my post. on x = we have year , y  = we have sales of bike .

Comment: That doesn't mean they do not contain NaN or inf values. [However](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html): `k: int, optional. The degree of the spline fit. It is recommended to use cubic splines. Even values of k should be avoided especially with small s values. 1 <= k <= 5`. So, maybe remove k=4?

Comment: It's still nothing ...

Comment: Well, that is all I can say without knowing what x, y are. Have you made sure that this condition is fulfilled: `The user is responsible for assuring that the values of x are unique.` And I suggest removing the entire sklearn part - it has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: ##select x,y ##
select2 = df.groupby('Customer_Age')['Customer_Gender'].value_counts().rename('count').reset_index()
x = np.array(pd.DataFrame(select2['Customer_Age']))
y = np.array(select2['count'])

Comment: We don't have your df. But if I have a series of repeated x-values, I get the same  output for `c`. You have to make sure before `interpolate.splrep(x, y, s=0, k=4)` that x-values are unique.

Comment: Im edited again .

Comment: So, each x-value exists as M and F? That explains it. Option 1: average each x-value before `interpolate.splrep()`. Option 2: create two splines, one for M, one for F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use dmatrix from patsy.
Let's say we have a df with column x, which we want to convert into B Spline basis.

```
from patsy import dmatrix
df_x_transformed = dmatrix('x + bs(x, knots = (10, 20, 30), degree = 3, 
                            include_intercept = False)', 
                          {'x': df[x]}, 
                          return_type = 'dataframe')
```

where bs(x) gets you the b splines, x adds the original column (optional).